# Não consigo imprimir os nome em vetor recebidos pelo scanf, necessito imprimir os 3 depois que as repetições do for termin0

Tags: c, char

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, idade;
    float peso, media_peso, media_idad;
    **char nome[3][11];**

        for(i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{           
            printf("digite seu nome \n");
            scanf("%s",&nome[i]);

            printf("digite sua idade \n");
            scanf ("%d",&idade);
            
            media_idad= media_idad+idade;
    
            printf("digite seu peso \n");
            scanf ("%f", &peso);
            
            media_peso= media_peso+peso;
}
 if(media_peso > 55)
  {
    media_peso/3;
    printf("media de pesos maior que 55 kilos\n");
  }
  
   **printf(" Nomes %s \n", nome[i]);**
   printf(" Media idade %f \n",media_idad/3);


system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui entender o que pretende com esta media_peso, da maneira como está não faz sentido mas você não explicou o que deseja calcular.
Para imprimir o array de nomes utilize um `for`.
Na leitura do nome (uma string) não utilize o `&`.

```
int main(void) {
    int i, idade;
    float peso, media_peso=0, media_idad=0;
    char nome[3][11];

    for(i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {           
            printf("digite seu nome \n");
            scanf("%s", nome[i]);

            printf("digite sua idade \n");
            scanf ("%d", &idade);
            
            media_idad = media_idad + idade;
    
            printf("digite seu peso \n");
            scanf ("%f", &peso);
            
            media_peso = media_peso + peso;
    }
    if (media_peso > 55) {
        media_peso = media_peso / 3;
        printf("media de pesos maior que 55 kilos: %f\n", media_peso);
    }
    for (i=0; i<3;i++)
        printf(" Nomes %s \n", nome[i]);
     
    printf(" Media idade %f \n",media_idad/3);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: mano muito obg tem 2 hrs que tava tentando resolver isso